# Placing UIButton over fullscreen UIWebView to close it when UIWebView fails to load

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uibutton, fullscreen

I have interstitial fullscreen ad in my iOS app. I do not have control on HTML code for ad. I do not wish to modify ads code provided by ad network.
Sometimes ad is not loading due to network problems.
There is no way to close interestitial. App is unusable after that.

I wish to place native close  UIButton over UIWebView. 
I do not use IB, I have to make such button programatically.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(closeAd:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Then put whatever code you like in the method

```
-(void)closeAd:(id)sender;
```

Comment: But how I will ensure that it would be higher then UIWebView created in same way but 3rdparty module? Is there something like z-index in HTML or TopMost property in Delphi.

Comment: Is **view** as UIWebView ? I am not sure if I can get view from 3rd party ad module.